# history.pushState on sub pages in an Angular.js application

Tags: angularjs, pushstate

I have a blank Angular.js 6 application that uses `PathLocationStrategy` for routing, and when on a subroute (e.g. `/test`) and executing the following:

```js
history.pushState({}, '', '#abc');
window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent('hashchange'));
```

I would expect the URL to be changed to `/test#abc` but instead changes the page and URL to the home page (`/#abc`).

This can be fixed by pretending with the base URL, for example:

```
history.pushState({}, '', (new URL(window.location.href)).pathname + '#abc');
```

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the `history.pushState` command in this case as it's executed externally from ads.

I also tried this in a new Angular 15 application, where similarly the URL updates to `/#abc` instead of `/test#abc` but the page didn't change.
However, in for example a new Nuxt.js app, it behaves as expected and stays on the test page and the URL becomes `/test#abc`. So it seems to be perhaps related to Angular.js.

Does anyone know how I can configure my Angular application so it stays on sub-pages when executing:

```js
history.pushState({}, '', '#abc');
window.dispatchEvent(new HashChangeEvent('hashchange'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing the following:

- Removed the `<base href="/">` element in file `src/index.html`
- Added provider `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }` in file `src/app/app.module.ts`
- Added `"deployUrl": "/"` to the `build` configuration in file `angular.json`